# 'Allowed countries' configuration not recognised in Paypal Express Checkout for shipping address validation

Tags: shipping, configuration, paypal-express, shipping-address, countries

I have a client's shop allowing orders to a national shipping address only. 
Using the integrated payment method 'PayPal Website Payments Standard' the paypal express checkout can be completed using any country as part of the shipping address - though allowed countries are limited to the national one only.

That's not the expected behaviour, is this a misconfiguration issue or is this simply not provided by the paypal express integration?

**Note:** There's some module installed to preset the shipping country (to the national one) for each magento session - could that be related?

I couldn't find any issues similar to mine, and I would be surprised if that's unresolved - so would be great if someone can point me into the right direction.

*Magento 1.9.2.1*
*php 7.0.2*

Answer (score 0):

For there's no answer yet, let me note that I haven't found any solution - just as kind of a workaround I managed to define high shipping costs for all countries my client doesn't actually ship to - shipping costs are then pulled properly by the paypal express checkout.

**Table based shipping costs example: [csv]**

```
DEU *   *   0   6.9
FRA *   *   0   19.9
ITA *   *   0   19.9
*   *   *   0   999.9
```

*Note: The last line represents 'all undefined' countries...*